# What code Jenkins pulls from Git on Pull-Request creation/update

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

When I'm opening/updating a Pull-Request from my **Development-Branch** to the **Master-Branch**, I want to trigger a Jenkins job.

This Jenkins job will *pull* the code from git (Bitbucket) and *build* it.

My very basic question is - what code exactly will be pulled?

Is it the code of my **Development-Branch**, or is the code of the Pull-Request **merged** with the **Master-Branch**?

Although the Pull-Request was not merged yet, maybe Jenkins will only simulate the merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer is:

> Jenkins job will pull the code of the Pull-Request merged with the
> Master-Branch and build it.

Actually, trigger just invoke the job start running follow up pipeline.

Which branch actually is being pull as define,

[image]

In your case, it's Master branch.

Comment: So if I define here my Master branch, then the merged master branch will be used, but I can also define here the development branch and then the development branch will be used, right?